# How to make Spark session read all the files recursively?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, recursion

Displaying the **directories** under which JSON files are stored:

```
$ tree -d try/
try/
├── 10thOct_logs1
├── 11thOct
│   └── logs2
└── Oct
    └── 12th
        └── logs3
```

Task is to read all logs using `SparkSession`.

**Is there an elegant way to read through all the files in directories and then sub-directories recursively**?

Few commands that I tried are prone to cause *unintentional* exclusion.

```
spark.read.json("file:///var/foo/try/<exp>")

+----------+---+-----+-------+
| <exp> -> | * | */* | */*/* |
+----------+---+-----+-------+
| logs1    | y | y   | n     |
| logs2    | n | y   | y     |
| logs3    | n | n   | y     |
+----------+---+-----+-------+
```

You can see in the above table that none of the three expressions matches all the directories (located at 3 different depths) at the same time. Frankly speaking, I wasn't expecting the exclusion of `10thOct_logs1` while using the third expression `*/*/*`.

This makes me conclude that whatever files or directories path match against the expression following last `/` is considered as an exact match, and everything else is ignored.

Comment: Did you try `**/*`?

Comment: Yes, `**/*` picks only `logs1` and `logs2`.

Comment: why use spark then?

Comment: I am relatively new to spark. The logs are millions in number. Heard that spark process it faster through some short of parallelism, so using it. Any recommendation that you can suggest?

Comment: Spark does seamless out of core processing and parallelism. However it comes with a lot of operating and configuraiton overhead. Nowdays even millions of log lines can fit into memory. In scala you could try just using parallel collecitons first
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-parallel-collections-in-scala-performance

You can try loading each record into as entry to parallel collection. Or if this does not fit into memory you can also create a parallel collection with the 3 large log files and then use the default map/filer/reduce api

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Update

A new option was introduced in Spark 3 to read from nested folder `recursiveFileLookup` :

```
spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").json("file:///var/foo/try")
```

---

For older versions, alternatively, you can use Hadoop `listFiles` to list recursively all the file paths and then pass them to Spark read:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{Path}

val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration

// get all file paths
val fromFolder = new Path("file:///var/foo/try/")
val logfiles = fromFolder.getFileSystem(conf).listFiles(fromFolder, true)
var files = Seq[String]()
while (logfiles.hasNext) {
       // one can filter here some specific files
       files = files :+ logfiles.next().getPath().toString
}

// read multiple paths
val df = spark.read.csv(files: _*)

df.select(input_file_name()).distinct().show(false)


+-------------------------------------+
|input_file_name()                    |
+-------------------------------------+
|file:///var/foo/try/11thOct/log2.csv |
|file:///var/foo/try/10thOct_logs1.csv|
|file:///var/foo/try/Oct/12th/log3.csv|
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately hadoop globs do not support recursive globs. See [Querying the Filesystem#File Patterns](https://holynull.gitbooks.io/oreilly-hadoop-the-definitive-guide-4th-edition/content/page/querying-the-filesystem.html)

There is an option to list multiple globs for each dir level.

> {a,b} alternation Matches either expression a or b

You have to be careful not to match same file twice, otherwise it will appear as duplicate.

```
spark.read.json("./try/{*logs*,*/*logs*,*/*/*logs*}")
```

You can also load multiple dataframes and union them

```
val dfs = List(
  spark.read.json("./try/*logs*"),
  spark.read.json("./try/*/*logs*"),
  spark.read.json("./try/*/*/*logs*")
)
val df = dfs.reduce(_ union _)
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, but it still requires prior knowledge of the files layout and some manual inputs. Thus, not recursive in nature.