# Reading Json files using pyspark

Tags: json, pandas, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read multiple json files from dbfs in databricks.

```
raw_df = spark.read.json('/mnt/testdatabricks/metrics-raw/',recursiveFileLookup=True)
```

This returns data for only 35 files whereas there are around 1600 files.

I tried to read some of the files (except those 35) using pandas and it returned data.

However the driver fails when I try to read all 1600 files using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

from glob import glob
jsonFiles = glob('/dbfs/mnt/testdatabricks/metrics-raw/***/*.json') 

dfList = []
for jsonFile in jsonFiles:
    df = pd.read_json(jsonFile)
    dfList.append(df)
    print("written :", jsonFile )
    
dfTrainingDF = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
```

Not sure why spark is not able to read all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").json("file:///dir1/subdirectory")

Ref: [How to make Spark session read all the files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528940/how-to-make-spark-session-read-all-the-files-recursively)

Comment: I have tried this. But it does not read all the 1600 files. it only reads 35 files

Comment: check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528940/how-to-make-spark-session-read-all-the-files-recursively