# Read a specific file from nested sub-folders

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading a single file from a subfolder its working fine

```
 val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("SparkAndHive")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/tmp/spark-warehouse2")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.registerAll(spark.sqlContext)

    
    val spatialRDD = ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD(spark.sparkContext, "src/main/resources/IND_rds")

    val spatialRDD = ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD(spark.sparkContext, "src/main/resources/IND_rrd")

    val rawSpatialDf = Adapter.toDf(spatialRDD,spark)
    rawSpatialDf.createOrReplaceTempView("rawSpatialDf")

    spark.sql("select * from rawSpatialDf").show
```

So problem is currently my folder structure is below

```
.
├── ind
│   ├── IND_rds
│   │   ├── IND_roads.dbf
│   │   ├── IND_roads.prj
│   │   ├── IND_roads.shp
│   │   └── IND_roads.shx
│   └── IND_rrd
│       ├── IND_rails.dbf
│       ├── IND_rails.prj
│       ├── IND_rails.shp
│       └── IND_rails.shx
├── nep
│   ├── NPL_rds
│   │   ├── NPL_roads.dbf
│   │   ├── NPL_roads.prj
│   │   ├── NPL_roads.shp
│   │   └── NPL_roads.shx
│   └── NPL_rrd
│       ├── NPL_rails.dbf
│       ├── NPL_rails.prj
│       ├── NPL_rails.shp
│       └── NPL_rails.shx
```

- > since currently **i have two country and each country has 2 subfolders** one road details and rails details
  > now problem is I just want to **create two rdd** to load every country road data in first rdd and second rdd to load every country rail data
- > so in my current approach I would be creating too many rdd and I would require to manually give the path of every road and rail dir
- In my current approach I would be creating 4 rdd manually and hardcode the paths of those folders manually

Is there any alternative approach to pick **all country** and there  respective **road and rail directory** dynamically from the nested folders

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving the complete code, but based on my understanding, you could do this better with partitioned table and spark sql module.

load data into dataframes is way more better than load into rdds.

In your table, you could leave two partitioned columns as country and rail and when you read the data, you could just specify the root directory instead of the path of root/country_name/rail_name. and the schema of the dataframe you obtain would be all the columns you have in your files + country_name + rail_name.

However you need to rename your directories first like this:

```
.
├── country_name=ind
│   ├── rail_name=IND_rds
│   │   ├── IND_roads.dbf
│   │   ├── IND_roads.prj
│   │   ├── IND_roads.shp
│   │   └── IND_roads.shx
│   └── rail_name=IND_rrd
│       ├── IND_rails.dbf
│       ├── IND_rails.prj
│       ├── IND_rails.shp
│       └── IND_rails.shx
├── country_name=nep
│   ├── rail_name=NPL_rds
│   │   ├── NPL_roads.dbf
│   │   ├── NPL_roads.prj
│   │   ├── NPL_roads.shp
│   │   └── NPL_roads.shx
│   └── rail_name=NPL_rrd
│       ├── NPL_rails.dbf
│       ├── NPL_rails.prj
│       ├── NPL_rails.shp
│       └── NPL_rails.shx
```

then:

```
 val df = spark.read.load("the root path")
 val df_ind = df.filter(col("country_name") === "ind")
```

for more info you can refer to the partition discovery section in this doc:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html

Alternatively, if you cannot rename the folder to this format:
refer to this link:
[How to make Spark session read all the files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528940/how-to-make-spark-session-read-all-the-files-recursively)
In simple words, if you are later then spark 3, you use recursiveFileLookup, otherwise you have to play with hdfs listFiles

Comment: The issue is i can't rename it because from the source more files will drop in and each time it drops a dir country name will be created as below 
├── UK
│   ├── UK_rds
│   │   ├── UK_roads.dbf
│   └── UK_rrd
│       ├── UK_rails.dbf
```
- > If i load the base path as val df = spark.read.load("the root path") then how will i call them separately ? 
 because at the end i would like to write all road details in one csv file and another file as rail details as output csv format 
i m new to spark not sure which approach to take for getting the final output
please tell me if its not clear

Comment: are there any alternative approach to solve the problem ?

Comment: @spark_dev answer edited

Comment: we can not use these methods because these are geometric file format thats the problem 
if its parquet file we can use recursiveFileLookup but i m not sure how do we look these on nested folders 
eg 
val recursiveLoadedDF = spark.read.format("parquet")
  .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
  .load("examples/src/main/resources/dir1")

It would be nice if someone can give a workaround

Comment: recursiveFileLookup is independent of the file format. what are your geometric files? I presume your files are text files, then: val recursiveLoadedDF = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") .text("examples/src/main/resources/dir1")

Comment: These are Shape File eg IND_roads.dbf, IND_roads.prj,IND_roads.shp 
you can check the post reference image for file format 
these are similar to GeoSpatial Shape files 
would appreciate to refer a alternative way to load these files recursive and read in different df or rdd

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex/wild characters

```
inputpath= "src/main/resources/[A-Za-z]\*/\*_rds"
inputpath= "src/main/resources/[A-Za-z]\*/\*_rrd"
```