How to read nested csv files dynamically to load data into single data frame
we have to read the csv files and put back to single temp tables, below structure of the files available in ADLS location, we have to read dynamically all the files. kindly suggest and provide samples.

/mnt/container/test/samples/sample2/data/sampledata/daily/YYYY=2022/MM=01/DD=01/file1.csv

we have to read dynamically if any partition folder to read the csv files. kindly suggest.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59530182/3238085
